# Store local image to upload in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, jquery-file-upload

I have to make an image input that will not upload the image. The images will be used in another page where it will be edited(cropped and draw over) and then uploaded.

I don't know how to do that, do you have any ideas? I'll probably be using this [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki).

Comment: While the answer provided works, it should be noted that browsers have a limited amount of bits you can store locally. So it is not a good idea to do that if you have big images or just too many. I would advice uploading into a temporary directory on the server to do what I wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have get the image using getElementByID. convert the image in to base64 and save in local storage

```
userimage = document.getElementById('imageId');
imageData = getBase64Image(userimage);
localStorage.setItem("imageData", imageData);

function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

insert the script in your second page for getting the image from localstorage and set to the image src

```
window.onload = function() {
 var getpicture = localStorage.getItem('imageData');
 var image = document.createElement('img');
 image.src = getpicture;
};
```

Comment: Is there any ways to store it without rendering the image in an img tag? Or should I just hide the tag?

Comment: set image display:none;